# how can i push appropriate XIB (Ipad or IPhone) without calling initWithNibName

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.2, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to push controller using

but for the universal app

i have to write..

```
if([[UIDevice current]UserInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterFaceIPad)
{
    MyViewController *controller = [[MYViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController_IPad"];


    [self.navigationCOntroller pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];

    else{
    MyViewController *controller = [[MYViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController_IPhone"];


    [self.navigationCOntroller pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Can i get solution to overcome the " if "
 condition and avoid the device check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two nibs, one for iPhone and one for iPad name them `MyViewController~iphone.xib` and `MyViewController~ipad.xib` (note: it's important to match the case!). Make sure they're both added to your target, and then in your code just do:

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MYViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController"];
[self.navigationCOntroller pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```